# Hiding a popup using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page which has multiple CSS only pop-ups implemented.
The popups work fine & close when the 'X' is clicked. However I wish for them to be closed when user clicks anywhere on the page. For that I implemented a short javascript code, which does close them on any click, but they dont open again (until page is refreshed). I am guessing the state is being saved as "none". How do i fix this?

The code:

```js
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.className === "overlay") {
    event.target.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="editbutton">       
<a class="btn btn-link" href="#popupedit">Edit</a></div>

<div id="popupedit" class="overlay">
<div class="popup10">
<a class="close" href="#"></a>
........
</div>
</div>

 <div class="editbutton">       
<a class="btn btn-link" href="#popupedit1">Edit</a></div>

<div id="popupedit1" class="overlay">
<div class="popup10">
<a class="close" href="#"></a>
........
</div>
</div>

 <div class="editbutton">       
<a class="btn btn-link" href="#popupedit2">Edit</a></div>

<div id="popupedit2" class="overlay">
<div class="popup10">
<a class="close" href="#"></a>
........
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2000;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup10 {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup10 h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup10 .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 10px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup10 .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup10 .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: In CSS attributes, there is no `display: hide`. you can use `display: none` instead.

Comment: my bad, it is indeed "none". I  must have copied the edits i was trying. The issue persists with "none" though.

Comment: `event.target.setAttribute("style", "display: none")` try this.

Comment: yes, the display state is being saved as "none". Where is the code which re-opens them?

Comment: @zynkn. Tried it, same issue, the popups will only open once, once closed with an outside click, wont open again.

Comment: @ADyson thats the part i need help with, the popups are meant to open with href="#popupedit" . But after clicking outside, it is closed & wont open again.

Comment: " the popups are meant to open with href="#popupedit""...well there must be some Javascript code somewhere which is driving that. That href on its own cannot open a popup. Are you using bootstrap modals, perhaps?

Comment: If so then see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-javascript for how to control bootrap modals using javascript

Comment: @ADyson , no this is a purely CSS driven popup that I picked from Codepen. I have added the full css part in the edit. There was no js element in it, I am trying to add js to give the functionality to close it if user clicks outside, unless there is another way to do this?

Comment: @Jarvis can you post a minimal working example of your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code you should update in javascript.

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.className === "btn btn-link") {
    document.getElementById('popupedit').style.display = "block";
  }
  if (event.target.className === "overlay") {
    event.target.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Why the popup is not opened again is that you set the **overlay** part `display: none` when clicking the part, but no process to set back to `display: block`.

So you should set the popup layout back to `display: block` again when clicking the edit button.

Please see the result working : https://jsfiddle.net/254xmyv7/3/

Hope this would be helpful. :)

Comment: Okay, I am implemented this & it works, the only issue is that since i have more than 10 pop-ups in the page, this code will work only for the one specifically declared , which is 'popupedit', what should i modify to make it work for all the pop-ups?

Comment: @Jarvis, not sure what structures would be out there. Could you elaborate on this question or another question by putting some detailed code?

Comment: I have added more code to the original post. In short the page is a list of buttons called edit, each button leading to a different popup differentiated with the pop up division id such as popupedit1, popupedit2  etc.... & button href as per the div

Comment: `if (event.target.className === "btn btn-link") {
    document.getElementById('popupedit').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('popupedit1').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('popupedit2').style.display = "block";
  }` If you are using the multiple popups, you should set the all `display:block` because they would be set to `none` whenever clicking the rest parts of the popups.

Comment: @Javis, please see the result. https://jsfiddle.net/254xmyv7/4/

Answer (score 2):

Although @Kevin Lee's code works, adding a long list of elements with getElementById isn't recommended. If you remove one of the popup elements or add one, you have to go back and manually change the code. You should consider instead looping through all the existing elements with the class 'overlay' and applying the property with a single line of code rather than 10 separate ones:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  var popups;
  if (event.target.className === "btn btn-link") {
    popups  = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay');
    console.log(popups[i]);
    for (let i = 0; i < popups.length; i++) {
      popups[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  if (event.target.className === "overlay") {
    event.target.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

This will save you a lot of time and potentially aggravation down the road. Working fiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/Vanadu/u7n30Lra/24/

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript, the window element gets the click, finds the element with the class 'overlay' and sets its style.display property to 'none'. Then, when you click the element to open the popup, that click is 'bubbling up' the DOM tree to the window, and the window then sets the display property to 'none' again before the popup can open.

One approach might be to prevent the click on the elements from 'bubbling up' and use the same class on the window level to control the popup that you use on the element level.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation